# How to compare java version strings in c++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have strings (Java version strings) like this:
"1.8.0_101"
"1.8.0_91"

Is there an easy way to determine which version is higher in c/c++?

I have used strcmp() so far. It compares version strings like "1.7.0" with "1.8.0" correctly, but when underscore character is involved it does not work anymore (because underscore has higher value in ASCII table than all numbers)

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did that work? How *didn't* that work? You do know [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here on stackoverflow? And how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: push the numbers onto two vectors, compare the vectors. voted to close as **too broad**.

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with Java; it's just a C++ string parsing exercise. Please learn to abstract away irrelevant technologies; it'll help you with your research and then you may not even need to ask.

Comment: Although, on second thoughts, for the sake of making the question useful and searchable, maybe the context is a good idea. Hmm. Not sure now.

Comment: `I have used strcmp() so far.` -- Stop writing code and think how you would do this with "pencil and paper".  Wouldn't you want to split the version into two parts, the first with the "." and the second part with the data after the underscore?  If you thought of it that way, you would have more success.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: this should be just an example to give you an idea of implementation. Your question lacks various points in order to make it a good question, anyway I'm going to try to help and give you a runnable example. The code could be improved and make it more robust.*

```
struct Version {
  int m_major;
  int m_minor;
  int m_release;
  int m_minor_release;

  Version() : m_major(-1),
              m_minor(-1),
              m_release(-1),
              m_minor_release(-1) { }

  // Convert a str to a version object
  explicit Version(const std::string& str_version) : Version() {
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t finder;

    // Cycle until find a character as '.' '-' '_'
    while (finder = str_version.find_first_of(".-_", offset),
           finder != std::string::npos) {
      int* p = nullptr;
      if (m_major == -1) {
        p = &m_major;
      } else if (m_minor == -1) {
        p = &m_minor;
      } else if (m_release == -1) {
        p = &m_release;
      } else {
        p = &m_minor_release;
      }

      *p = std::stoi(str_version.substr(offset, finder - offset));
      offset = finder + 1;
   }

    if (offset != str_version.size() && m_minor_release == -1) {
      m_minor_release = std::stoi(
        str_version.substr(offset,std::string::npos));
    }
  }

  bool operator<(const Version& oth) const {
    // compare this version with another one
  }
};
```

I hope you can find this little example useful for your problem implementation.